# How to uninstall trial software safely/completely on a Mac?

Tags: mac, uninstall

Is there any way to safeguard your harddrive when installing trial software?

I want to make sure each and every file that was installed gets deleted, is that possible?

Comment: Related questions about uninstalling applications in general: [1](http://superuser.com/questions/92504/uninstall-on-mac-os-x) [2](http://superuser.com/questions/144387/how-to-uninstall-software-on-a-mac) [3](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/470/how-do-i-uninstall-a-program-completely-on-a-mac) [4](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41773/how-to-fully-uninstall-an-app-on-os-x) [5](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50767/is-there-a-standard-uninstall-procedure-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the application, you can just go to `Applications`, right-click on the file and click `Move to Trash`, and that will remove the application and all of its supporting files.

This isn't always the case, because certain applications will add configuration files or other packages that aren't actually part of the application (won't appear when you click on 'show package contents').

Best way to handle these is with another program. There are programs designed to hunt down support files for applications and remove them from your machine such as [AppCleaner](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/15/delete-applications-mac-os-x-appcleaner/).

Comment: Note that deleting the application bundle does not remove personalized files in your `~/Library`, which contain e.g. preferences or supporting resources. Programs that come with an installer, especially those requiring admin privileges, are also much more difficult to remove.

Answer (score 1):

[AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) will do this for you. Drag the app onto the app and it will locate all the support files and offer to remove them along with the app itself. It's free.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of pkg installers, you can see what files would be installed by them with something like `lsbom -s ~/Desktop/Install\ USB\ Overdrive.pkg/Contents/Archive.bom`.

`/var/db/receipts` contains bom files for previously installed packages and applications installed from the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is fine a program that searches your hard drive and makes a list of what you have on your hard drive.  Then after you install some trial software, it runs and see if any files were added.  It's a bonus if it stores the hash of files to see if they change as well.

However, there are certain files that will always fail the hash check which are files like, log files.

Another way to do this is to install trial software in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr: At 1,000+ words, this is a long, detailed, complex answer.  Short version: (1) Use a filesystem search utility, like `fd`, to peruse across your disk for relevant files & directories to remove, which is probably sufficient for a lot of cases.  (2) Using a package manager like Homebrew also helps.  (3) A more bulletproof approach is to conduct installs inside a VM and diff the filesystem before and after, but of course that's a lot more work.**

---

*Disclaimer: I am a software engineer.  This answer involves more terminal usage than the average user may be comfortable with.*

### I. Introduction

> Is there any way to safeguard your harddrive when installing trial software?
>
> I want to make sure each and every file that was installed gets deleted, is that possible?

In general, no, it is not *trivially* possible, in the sense that there is *no magic bullet* for completely uninstalling an arbitrary application on macOS.

The reason is: there isn't a system in place for tracking every filesystem level change from pre- vs post- install of an app.  If we had this, then we could simply review the diff, ignore the irrelevant parts, and remove the added files.

More tediously, if the installation modifies files, you would need to track the contents of those relevant modified files in order to revert their contents back to a pre-install state.

You can use one of the GUI uninstaller tools as others have mentioned, but they are problematic for a few reasons: (1) they are mostly paid software, (2) they may not tell you exactly which files they're removing, and (3) they may not actually provide complete removals.

---

### II. Use a Package Manager like Homebrew (`brew`) for cleaner (un)installs

A [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) is a tool that automates installing, upgrading, and removing (uninstalling) software.

Note: The Mac App Store (MAS) also functions *somewhat* like a package manager, but in contrast to most others, it is closed source so the details are a black box.

If you can get an app via Homebrew, prefer that to via the MAS, because you can see in the formula exactly which files will be removed ("zapped") (*only when you explicitly tell brew to do so*).

For example, take a look at the [Sublime Text formula page](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/sublime-text) or its [formula code / config](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/4c385a75364ff3b7e4fff1da4d66aaa49c8ec790/Casks/sublime-text.rb) itself.

---

### III. A General Approach to Thorough Uninstalls

From a more pragmatic standpoint, here are some steps that you can do yourself for free, without any GUI tools, and that will provide a *more complete* removal:

**1. Use some sort of system-wide file search tool.**

- I recommend [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd), but you can also use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) or others.
- Note that the built-in search in Finder.app is woefully inadequate for this task.  To verify this, simply compare the results it presents vs the aforementioned tools.

**2. Perform system-wide searches for the name of the company and the name of the app you're trying to remove.**

- For example, I'm trying to completely uninstall [Tower](https://www.git-tower.com/mac) (a GUI Git client), which offers no proper uninstaller, and leaves *tons* of files littered across the disk without documentation on how users can clean them up.  In the world of software, this is being a bad citizen.

**3. Remove the relevant files.**

- **You need to be VERY CAREFUL here**: running `rm` in the terminal is permnanent and irreversible.  If you are not comfortable with it, instead open the directories in the Finder (`open <dir>`) and drag the items to the Trash there.

[This approach is basically what the paid GUI apps do with their "secret sauce" being an index of *App A (Version V)* creates *files / directories X, Y, Z*.  As you can imagine, the exact set of files changes over time.]

#### Improvement: Use a VM to Increase Isolation

There are some other ideas you can try, like making a complete index of the filesystem with SHAs pre- and post-install (https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/40794/1788).  In a real-world filesystem, this approach would contain a lot of noise / many unrelated false positives though.

One technique you can use to reduce that further is to conduct an isolated installation in a virtual machine (VM).  If you have an Apple Silicon Mac, you can run macOS on top of macOS via Apple's Virtualization framework ([example](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2022/07/how-to-use-free-virtualization-apps-to-safely-test-the-macos-ventura-betas/)).  For Intel Macs, you can do this via VirtualBox ([example](https://samiyuru.com/blog/install-mac-on-vbox-on-mac)).

The other benefit of this approach is that software may plant files using filenames that don't contain their company or app name.

### IV. An Example: Tower

The name of the company that makes Tower is Four Nova, so my initial searches were: `four nova`, `fournova`, and `tower`.  For multi-word names, you may want to try common variations like joining the words on underscores or hyphens.

In this case, the first search returned nothing, the second search returned dozens of files and directories, and the third search returned hundreds of files on my system but with many irrelevant false positives.  So, let's focus on the second one to start:

```shell
$ cd /
$ fd fournova
Users/taylor/Library/Caches/com.plausiblelabs.crashreporter.data/com.fournova.Tower3/
Users/taylor/Library/Caches/com.plausiblelabs.crashreporter.data/com.fournova.Tower2/
Users/taylor/Library/Caches/com.fournova.Tower2/
Users/taylor/Library/Caches/com.fournova.Tower3/
Users/taylor/Library/HTTPStorages/com.fournova.Tower2/
Users/taylor/Library/HTTPStorages/com.fournova.Tower3/
Users/taylor/Library/Preferences/com.fournova.Tower2.plist.A3m3T1k
Users/taylor/Library/Preferences/com.fournova.Tower3.plist
Users/taylor/Library/Preferences/com.fournova.Tower2.plist
Users/taylor/Library/Saved Application State/com.fournova.Tower2.savedState/
Users/taylor/Library/Saved Application State/com.fournova.Tower3.savedState/
Users/taylor/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments/com.fournova.tower2.sfl2
Users/taylor/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments/com.fournova.tower3.sfl2
Users/taylor/Library/Application Support/com.fournova.Tower2/
Users/taylor/Library/Application Support/com.fournova.Tower3/
private/var/folders/gk/_y2ck2qx0zddmy542ftyxj180000gn/C/com.fournova.Tower2/
private/var/folders/gk/_y2ck2qx0zddmy542ftyxj180000gn/C/com.fournova.Tower3/
System/Volumes/Data/Users/taylor/Library/Caches/com.plausiblelabs.crashreporter.data/com.fournova.Tower2/
System/Volumes/Data/Users/taylor/Library/Caches/com.plausiblelabs.crashreporter.data/com.fournova.Tower3/
System/Volumes/Data/Users/taylor/Library/Caches/com.fournova.Tower2/
System/Volumes/Data/Users/taylor/Library/Caches/com.fournova.Tower3/
System/Volumes/Data/Users/taylor/Library/HTTPStorages/com.fournova.Tower3/
System/Volumes/Data/Users/taylor/Library/HTTPStorages/com.fournova.Tower2/
System/Volumes/Data/Users/taylor/Library/Preferences/com.fournova.Tower2.plist
System/Volumes/Data/Users/taylor/Library/Preferences/com.fournova.Tower3.plist
System/Volumes/Data/Users/taylor/Library/Preferences/com.fournova.Tower2.plist.A3m3T1k
System/Volumes/Data/Users/taylor/Library/Saved Application State/com.fournova.Tower2.savedState/
System/Volumes/Data/Users/taylor/Library/Saved Application State/com.fournova.Tower3.savedState/
System/Volumes/Data/Users/taylor/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments/com.fournova.tower3.sfl2
System/Volumes/Data/Users/taylor/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments/com.fournova.tower2.sfl2
System/Volumes/Data/Users/taylor/Library/Application Support/com.fournova.Tower2/
System/Volumes/Data/Users/taylor/Library/Application Support/com.fournova.Tower3/
System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/gk/_y2ck2qx0zddmy542ftyxj180000gn/C/com.fournova.Tower2/
System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/gk/_y2ck2qx0zddmy542ftyxj180000gn/C/com.fournova.Tower3/
```

You can see that these paths fall into a few groups:

- `~/Library/...`

  - `Application Support/`

    - `com.apple.sharedfilelist/...` - my guess is that these are your recent ly opened files for the app
    - `com.fournova.Tower3/...` - the app's database of your repo metadata etc
  - `Caches/...` - the app's subdirs in caches are safe to delete
  - `HTTPStorages/com.fournova.Tower3/` - on my system, this was an empty SQLite database... I couldn't find an official reference on this one
  - `Preferences/...` - the app's preference file is safe to delete
  - `Saved Application State/com.fournova.Tower3.savedState/` - appears to store information about open windows across launches of the app
- `/private/var/folders/...` - per-user temporary files and caches that should be safe to remove ([ref 1](https://magnusviri.com/what-is-var-folders.html), [ref 2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/176371/1788))
- `/System/Volumes/Data/...` - I believe all of these can be safely ignored as firmlinks back to the main disk ([ref 1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/367159/1788))

As you may notice, I have multiple versions of Tower installed.  I believe "Tower 2" is v2.x from ~2018 and "Tower 3" is the current version, (which is actually "Version 9" according to https://www.git-tower.com/release-notes/mac).  To keep this answer focused, I'm only going to describe removing "Tower 3".

It turns out that there is a [Tower 3 formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/4c385a75364ff3b7e4fff1da4d66aaa49c8ec790/Casks/tower.rb) for Homebrew, which aside from the app, on uninstall removes the following files:

```
"~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments/com.fournova.tower*.sfl2"
"~/Library/Application Support/com.fournova.Tower*"
"~/Library/Caches/com.fournova.Tower*"
"~/Library/Preferences/com.fournova.Tower*.plist"
```

As you can see, we independently discovered all of these files and more by using `fd`.  So in this case, a simple `brew uninstall tower` would be insufficient to perform a full cleanup.

In any case, I wanted to start there to see if it's sufficient to reset the Tower app to a fresh state.  (It was not.)

Next, I tried a zap uninstall: `brew uninstall --zap tower`.  (Tower does not remove the files to zap by default; adding the `--zap` flag does.)

On my system, this *was* sufficient to reset Tower to a fresh state.

That said, if you want to continue with a thorough removal, proceed by running `rm -rf <path>` for each of the above paths, where `<path>` is the path you want to remove.  You may need to preface the command with `sudo` for some directories, or just run `sudo !!` after the command fails to automatically repeat the previous command with sudo added.

Disclaimer: If you are not absolutely sure what a certain path is, research it and see if others have documented it.  Only remove paths once you understand what they are.  If you are unsure, try renaming it, such as adding an `_old` suffix to the end, that way you can reverse it if needed.